# need help in translating silverlight 4 code to silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am extremely new to silverlight working on a new control called pivotviewer in silverlight 5.
I am trying to write a doubleclick event for the pivot viewer from an existing silverlight 4 code.

```
//double click event
private void PivotViewerControl_ItemDoubleClicked(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
{
    PivotItem piv_item =PivotViewerControl1.GetItem(e.ItemId);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(piv_item.Href))
    {
        PivotViewerControl1.CurrentItemId = e.ItemId;
        OpenLink(piv_item.Href);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Web Page...");
    }
}
```

while translating this to silverlight 5 where pivotviewer is inbuilt control the following stub is created for the event.

```
private void PivotViewerControl_ItemDoubleClicked(object sender, PivotViewerItemDoubleClickEventArgs e)
{  
   //here the pivotviewercontrol has not getitem()  in silverlight 5 so How do i get the currently selected 
   //Item on the double click
}
```

Also I am not getting the images on the page load itself.  My page load code is as follows

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PivotViewerControl.Loaded += PivotViewerControl_Loaded;
}

void PivotViewerControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _cxml = new CxmlCollectionSource(new Uri(MauritiusCollectionUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    _cxml.StateChanged += _cxml_StateChanged;
}

void _cxml_StateChanged(object sender, CxmlCollectionStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState == CxmlCollectionState.Loaded)
    {                          
        PivotViewerControl.PivotProperties = _cxml.ItemProperties.ToList();
        PivotViewerControl.ItemTemplates =_cxml.ItemTemplates;
        PivotViewerControl.ItemsSource =_cxml.Items;
    }
}
```

On running I am only getting the images when I sort or do some search can anyone tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the double click event I have able to translate is as follows

```
    private void PivotViewerControl_ItemDoubleClicked(object sender,   
    PivotViewerItemDoubleClickEventArgs e)
    {
        PivotViewerItem piv_item = (PivotViewerItem)e.Item;
        if(piv_item.Properties[0]!=null && piv_item.Properties[0].ToString()!=string.Empty)
        {
            OpenLink(piv_item.GetPropertyValue("Href")[0].ToString());
        }
}
```